# Integrate a Lua editor into C# program

Tags: c#, editor, lua, code-completion

I'm doing a POC (Proof of concept) for a little open source project, to integrate Lua into c# looks pretty straight forward, but for this project we want to go a little further. We want to be able to edit Lua scripts from within our C# program (WPF client but we can go for winforms if that what it takes), the IDE needs basic code completion and that we can add our C# objects and methods (The ones you will be able to reach from the Lua scripts while running) so they will be auto completed.. Are they such a API available for C#?

edit: Schollii wanted some example code that i want code completion for

```
while true do
    Mouse:setY(TrackIR:getPitch())
end
```

where Mouse and TrackIR are c# objects accessible from Lua script

Answer (score 3):

If you want to integrate a Lua editor with syntax highlighting C#, IMO the easiest way is to go for the [Scintilla](http://scintilla.org/) control, which is available in C# through [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/). It already contains highlighter for the Lua language, and is relatively easy to embed and use.

For interfacing Lua with C#, you can use [LuaInterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/) and back. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339917/luainterface-docs) for documentation links.

Code completion will not be an easy task if you require completion beyond the standard library, which can be described in a simple dictionary. With Lua being a dynamic language, it is not trivial to deduce the contents of a variable before actually running the code up to a given point - it is not impossible, take a look at [lua-inspect](https://github.com/davidm/lua-inspect) which is available for SciTE and ViM and allows code inspection (but it's not perfect).

If you want to try code in a running environment - i.e. you have a Lua state running with modules loaded and variables set - you can get inspired by Advanced Readline Support patch at [LuaPowerPatches](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaPowerPatches) and adapt it to your enviroment in C#. It supports among other:

- Completion of keywords and global variable names.
- Recursive and metatable-aware completion of variable names.
- Context sensitive delimiter completion.

Comment: We have to be realistic here, I think the best middle way is to just implement Code completion for our own global variables, but will take a look at your links.. thanks!

Comment: @Anders Just a friendly comment: given you didn't say how advanced you needed the code completion to be, Michal's answer is excellent, ie I find "we have to be realistic" and "all I need is completion on global variables" somewhat impolite.

Comment: @Anders Could you provide some examples of partially written code that would appear in your editor and the desired completion, thx

Comment: I did give the answer a useful-click, thats not impolite is it... Code example in edited question

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want an embeddable editor that can have code completion and syntax highlighting, preferably WPF based. It doesn't need to explicitly support Lua.

Have a look at [Avalon Edit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx). Here is an [article about it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx)

You will have to implement the highlighting file and completions yourself within the framework it provides - but that looks easy enough.

Comment: Looks very interesting can you add custom global objects and their methods to code completion database?

Comment: I searched the net, but couldn't find if there is an existing Xshd for Lua, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such libs. Some tool you will likely need/find useful are [Luainterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/) and some open-source Lua editors that provide code comppletion such as blua and Scite. Note that code completion comes in different flavors, each with pros/cons in terms of power, ease of implementation, etc. For instance if you just want to provide a list of possible words that correspond to objects in global Lua namespace then you don't need much at all; if OTOH you want code completion to work with table fields and objects and various levels of nesting, work will be much increased.

Comment: You aren't kidding. I have spent the last 2 years on it.